Why does directSupertypes(TypeMirror) return an IntersectionType containing only two bounds when given Object[]'s array type?
If I invoke javax.lang.model.util.Types#directSupertypes(TypeMirror) on a TypeMirror corresponding to java.lang.Object[] (an array type), the resulting list is of size 1. The sole element of the list is an intersection type whose bounds are types corresponding to Cloneable and Serializable. Note the distinct lack of a type corresponding to java.lang.Object.
Note further that the toString() output of this type is java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Cloneable (note the presence of java.lang.Object in this output).
The JLS section 4.10.3 says:

Object >1 Object[]
Cloneable >1 Object[]
java.io.Serializable >1 Object[]

The javadoc (specification, contract) is of no help here, saying only:

Returns the direct supertypes of a type. The interface types, if any, will appear last in the list. For an interface type with no direct super-interfaces, a type mirror representing java.lang.Object is returned. The type java.lang.Object has no direct supertype (JLS 8.1.4, 8.1.5) so an empty list is returned for the direct supertypes of a type mirror representing java.lang.Object.

Why, then, does the type corresponding to java.lang.Object:

show up in the intersection type's toString() output
not show up in the intersection type's bounds
…?

Alternatively, or possibly in addition, why are there not three direct supertypes returned in the list? (I'm guessing some arcana about the primordial nature of arrays.)
Finally, why does the return value of directSupertypes not correspond to the rules of the JLS in this case?

There is unlikely an "interesting" answer to this. This is just how the compiler is written. From what I saw in the source code, this super type of array types is hardcoded, and there is a comment referring to JLS 10.8. I suspect that doing it this way is equivalent to the definition of direct super types in the JLS. And the java.lang.Object is also just how the toString implementation handles intersection types of only interface types. It is designed to also output the super type of the intersection.

Hmm; OK; how would I know from reading its contract that the directSupertypes method behaves in this fashion?
